# PHP - how to create object or associative array from a JSON string

Tags: php, javascript, arrays, json, object

I need to create an array or an object from a given string. String is received in a post and is a serialized js object.

I get a string like:

```
{'id': n, 'propery 1': 'something', 'propery 2': 'something else', etc.}
```

or

```
{'whatever': bla bla, etc.} (without the id part).
```

I need to transform that in a php object or array or... something usable.

I'm aware that I could extract the substrings or `explode(': ', $string)` but I not really efficient. The received strings are really close to json format (with only 1 or 2 exceptions that I can treat separately).

Comment: Actualy the examples You provided us are exactly the JSON format... Do You have any proof it is not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use json_decode($string) ==> php Object (or array if you force with a param).

Use json_encode($array) ==> string

Answer (score 1):

Looks like JSON. You can use json_decode(): http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Answer (score 1):

You can use JSON decode method in PHP: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Answer (score 1):

Here's what you need json_decode : http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Answer (score 1):

you can use `json_encode()`. http://in.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Comment: This is not what the OP needs... He does not want to encode the data, but **decode** them...